# "Level" scope in local temporary tables sql server

Tags: sql-server, scope, temp-tables

I am reading a book mentioning

> Local temporary tables are visible throughout the level that created them, across batches, and in all inner levels of the call stacks. So if you create a temporary table in a specific level in your code and then execute a dynamic batch or a stored procedure, the inner batch can access the temporary table.

and

> Table variables are not visible even across batches in the same level

From other sources, what I understand is that local temporary tables are visible to the session that created it and destroyed when the session closes.

So what is "level" and "inner levels of the call stacks" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picture a stored procedure called `A` than, in turn, calls two stored procedures, `B` and then `C`<sup>1</sup>.

Each of these stored procedures creates a temporary table with the same name, prefixed (of course)  by `#` (so, `A` creates `#A`) as their first action, before running any further code.

You execute the following code in query analyser:

```
CREATE TABLE #F (ID INT NOT NULL)
EXEC A
GO
EXEC A
```

Code in `A` can work with tables `#F` and `#A`.

Code in `B` can work with tables `#F`, `#A` and `#B`

Code in `C` can work with tables `#F`, `#A` and `#C`

Despite `B` and `C` being at the same "level" (they were both called from `A`), `C` cannot access the temp table that `B` created (it was [destroyed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) when `B` exited).

---

<sup>1</sup>

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
AS
    CREATE TABLE #A (ID INT NOT NULL)
    EXEC B
    EXEC C
```

Comment: How about table variable ? Will table variable @tabA declared in A (after your CREATE TABLE #A) be visible to B and C ?

Comment: To my understanding variable does not span across batches. I remember reading somewhere that an EXEC will be an isolated transaction itself. Will a call such as EXEC B be an implied batch and/or transaction ?

Comment: @Kenny - table variables are only visible within the same scope that created them. Scopes, batches and transactions are actually three separate concepts. But the comments here on SO aren't going to be suitable if you want to flesh out those details. `EXEC` creates a new *scope*. *Batches* are the sets of statements sent by a client (tools such as SSMS obscure these lines by allowing you to write multiple batches separated by `GO`s, which the tool then splits before sending to the server). Transactions are orthogonal to both of these.

Comment: @Kenny - the one remaining detail I can think of is that each batch is, implicitly, submitted to the server, logically, as an `EXEC` - which is why table variables aren't visible across batches - because they're in different scopes.